# Gradle project sync failed with a AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I have been encountering this issue whenever I start up Android Studio. I would get a notification stating 'Gradle project sync failed'. The error code is as follows:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/####/AndroidStudioProjects/TEST/app/build.gradle' 
line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Users/####/.android/build-ca 
che.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s
/Users/####/.android/build-cache.lock
```

I tried several solutions but none solved the issue. Any suggestions?